# Name mangling in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Consider the following program.

```
 class A():
     class __B():
         def __c(self):
             pass
a = A()
dir(a)
['_A__B', '__doc__', '__module__']
dir(a._A__B)
['_B__c', '__doc__', '__module__']

 ^^^^^^^
```

Why is this not `___B__c` why is not there not `3` `_`s.What is the logic here?
According to name mangling,it should be `_class` and `class` here is `__B`.So where are the `2` `__`s

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's right there in [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) (emphasis added):

> Any identifier of the form __spam (at least two leading underscores, at most one trailing underscore) is textually replaced with _classname__spam, where classname is the current class name **with leading underscore(s) stripped**

Comment: Do u know If there is any particular reason why python does it or its just the language syntax set that way