# How to access outer class member from an inner class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, inner-classes

How to access an outer class member from an inner class in Python 3?

Below is my code snippet.

```
class Outer:    
    def __init__(self):
        self.__x = 20
        self.__str = "Outer Class"

    def show(self):
        self.i1 = self.Inner(Outer())
        self.i1.display()

    def fn(self):
        print("Hello from fn() of Outer Class")
        print("str : ", self.__str)

    class Inner:
        def __init__(self, outer):
            self.__str_in = "Inner Class"
            self.outer = outer

        def display(self):
            print("str_in : ", self.__str_in)
            print("Inside display() of Inner Class")
            # print("x : ", self.outer.__x)
            # print("str : ", self.outer.__str)
            # self.outer.fn()


obj = Outer()
obj.show()
```

If I execute the commented lines, it throws an error saying -

```
line 23, in display
    print("x : ", self.outer.__x)
AttributeError: type object 'Outer' has no attribute '_Inner__x'
```

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you didn't understand correctly the meaning of `name mangling`, that's exactly what you're doing when adding the double leading score in your variable name.

When setting up the variable as `self.__x`, what you're actually doing is telling the world outside your class that it can only be accessed this way when operating inside the `Outer` class. If you try to access outside, lets say add after the definition of `obj` the following `print(obj.__x)`, you'll see the same problem.

The name mangling means that when accessing the variable outside of the scope of your class, you should call the variable `_ClassName__variableName`, so, in our example, you should use `print(obj._Outer__x)` to be able to `print` the variable.

Since your `Inner` class works the same way, as an outside scope, the simplest solution would be to rewrite your `display` method this way:

```
def display(self):
    print("str_in : ", self.__str_in)
    print("Inside display() of Inner Class")
    print("x : ", self.outer._Outer__x)
    print("str : ", self.outer._Outer__str)
    self.outer.fn()
```

Now, other thing I noticed, and can generate problems if you didn't do this consciously, is the call `self.i1 = self.Inner(Outer())`. Here you're not using the same object data that you instantiated as `obj`, but creating a new instance of `Outer` and sending this to `Inner`.
***And what's the problem with this?*** 
Let's say you added the following lines:

```
obj = Outer()
obj._Outer__x = 10
obj.show()
```

Then the output of your `show()` will always be `x: 20`, because this change you've done in the variable, was made to an instance that was not passed to `Inner`.

If it's not the behaviour you were aiming for, just change this line to:

```
self.i1 = self.Inner(self)
```

So now you're effectively passing the instantiated object to `Inner`

Comment: Welcome, @SarfarazHussain!

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are passing **the class** instead of **an instance** in `self.i1 = self.Inner(Outer)`, and `self.__str` is an **instance** attribute.

There is also another problem. You are using `__` prefix which is subjected to [name mangling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619202/name-mangling-in-python), so try to avoid that.

You have 2 ways to fix this:

- Pass the instance, ie `self.i1 = self.Inner(self)`

or

- Make `_str` a class attribute:

  ```
  class Outer:
      _str = "Outer Class"  # NOTE THE SINGLE _

      def __init__(self):
          self._x = 20 # NOTE THE SINGLE _

      ...
  ```

Comment: Thank you. But I have tried both ways and still, it is not working. The same error is showing up.

Comment: @SarfarazHussain Because you are probably still using `__`

Comment: It worker :D Thank you.. But can we say what is the problem with __? I studied that __ is for private, _ for protected.

Comment: @SarfarazHussain https://dbader.org/blog/meaning-of-underscores-in-python

Comment: The problem is with understanding the `name mangling` and its effects outside the class @SarfarazHussain!
Check my answer, where I detail it and present the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53692466/10642035